# How to Cache Ienumerable var

Tags: caching, ienumerable

I have the following code :

```
XDocument xResponse = XDocument.Parse(strXMLResponse);

var vMyData = from xmyInfo in xResponse.Descendants("Result").Elements("item")
select new myProporties
{
      strmyInfo1 = ((string)xmyInfo .Element("el1")).Trim(),
      strmyInfo2 = ((string)xmyInfo .Element("el2")).Trim(),
      strmyInfo3 = (string)xAudioinfo.Element("el3")
};
```

Now I want to cache the vMyData having dependency on strXMLResponse.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vMyData = vMyData.ToList();
```

This will enumerate your `IEnumerable` and capture the result into a `List<T>` (which is then idempotent).